# Hide certain files in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I would like to hide object files (*.o) in the Vim NERDTree plugin. Does the plugin support this feature, yet?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You want to use the NERDTreeIgnore option, for example:
`let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.o$', '\~$']`

Do :help NERDTreeIgnore for more information.

Comment: Just to add you can use `f` to show/hide ignored files

Answer (score 7):

Hoping this might be helpful as per New NerdTree Documentation.

```
// put this in your .vimrc
set wildignore+=*.pyc,*.o,*.obj,*.svn,*.swp,*.class,*.hg,*.DS_Store,*.min.*

// Nerdtree config for wildignore
let NERDTreeRespectWildIgnore=1
```