# How can I hide and show files easily in vim nerdtree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I use vim for everything, and when in javascript, I want to ignore my node_modules directory, but reveal it when I need it. I've already applied the solution using NERDTreeIgnore, but that keeps it hidden all the time.
https://superuser.com/a/185661

Some things are normally hidden, such as .gitignore, because they start with a period. I can use shift+i to show the hidden files, and that's great because I often need to edit these, but I can mostly leave them hidden. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057406/5114)

I want to hide node_modules, but I would like shift+i to reveal that just like the normal hidden files.

Additionally, I use python, and I want the *.pyc files to be hidden always. (I already have this in my NERDTreeIgnore.)

This seems like a thing that could have a very simple solution, but I haven't found it yet. I'm not opposed to writing some script to do this, but I'm not very well versed in vimscript and I don't want to break the existing behavior for normally hidden files and shift+i.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERDTree.txt#L581 ?